# SQL - How to compute percentage and add to query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

After using this query:

```
SELECT 
    ClientCipher, SUM(LastWeeklyAccessCount) AS ClientAccessCount 
FROM 
    SSLAccessClient 
WHERE 
    ClientCipher IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    ClientCipher
```

This is the result:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     ClientCipher    |    AccessCount   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     TLS 1.0         |         2        |
|     TLS 1.1         |         2        |
|     TLS 1.2         |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

How can I append to this result the percentage of clients using TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, etc.? Something like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     ClientCipher    |    AccessCount   |    Percentage    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     TLS 1.0         |         2        |      25%         |
|     TLS 1.1         |         2        |      25%         |
|     TLS 1.2         |         4        |      50%         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You will need to provide the table structure as well.

Comment: ClientId int, ClientCipher varchar (512), AccessCount int. Percentage should be number of counts per individual TLS / total of counts, 2/8 * 100 in the first case and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way do not use Window function (probably work for older version).

```
SELECT
    a. ClientCipher
    , 100.00 * a.ClientAccessCount / b.TotalSum AS Percentage
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ClientCipher, SUM(LastWeeklyAccessCount) AS ClientAccessCount 
        FROM 
            SSLAccessClient 
        WHERE 
            ClientCipher IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP BY 
            ClientCipher
    ) a
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT SUM(LastWeeklyAccessCount) AS TotalSUM
        FROM
            SSLAccessClient
        WHERE
            ClientCipher IS NOT NULL
    ) b;
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/NDIN22703)

```
SELECT 
       DISTINCT
       [ClientCipher],
       -- just for debug
       COUNT([ClientCipher]) over (partition by [ClientCipher]) num,
       COUNT([ClientCipher]) over () den,

       -- your percentage
       COUNT([ClientCipher]) over (partition by [ClientCipher]) *1.0 /
       COUNT([ClientCipher]) over () perc
FROM Table1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: You make it seem so simple. I should start learning more SQL. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be

```
;with cte as (
        SELECT  ClientCipher, SUM(LastWeeklyAccessCount) AS ClientAccessCount 
        FROM    SSLAccessClient 
        WHERE   ClientCipher IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP BY  ClientCipher
)
Select *
      ,Percentage = ClientAccessCount * 100.0 / (Select sum(ClientAccessCount) from cte)
 From  cte
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an aggregate function for the total

```
    SELECT 
        ClientCipher, 
        SUM(LastWeeklyAccessCount) AS ClientAccessCount , 
        (SUM(LastWeeklyAccessCount) / SUM(LastWeeklyAccessCount) OVER () ) * 100
    FROM 
        SSLAccessClient 
    WHERE 
        ClientCipher IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY 
        ClientCipher
```

Comment: I dont think that will work, because you put the window function with the `group by`

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do with window functions:

```
SELECT ClientCipher, SUM(LastWeeklyAccessCount) AS ClientAccessCount ,
       SUM(LastWeeklyAccessCount) / SUM(SUM(LastWeeklyAccessCount)) OVER () as Percentage
FROM SSLAccessClient 
WHERE ClientCipher IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY ClientCipher;
```

This is the best way to write the query.

Note that SQL Server does integer division, so you might need to convert to numbers.  So, it is possible that the expression you want is:

```
       SUM(LastWeeklyAccessCount) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(LastWeeklyAccessCount)) OVER () as Percentage
```